# Can a Thunderbolt iMac be used in target display mode while booted into Windows 7?

Tags: bootcamp, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display, target-display

Slightly different than what I'm seeing in search:

If I have my iMac booted into Windows 7, can I (via Thunderbolt) use the iMac as a target display from my Thunderbolt MacBook Pro running OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Target Display Mode is not supported from Boot Camp

Ref: [Apple KB - Use your iMac as a display with Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204592)

> If your iMac is currently started up in Windows, it won't enter Target
>   Display Mode. Target Display Mode isn't supported in Boot Camp.